# Big json handling with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Hi guys i have some problems handling a big json input with jmeter (about 55 k rows). Initially i tried to use the function

```
${__FileToString(myPath/test.json,,)}
```

but seems like this doesn't work properly: I got another error during the process.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "1["

    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP.decodeQuery(RequestViewHTTP.java:336) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.5]

    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP.getQueryMap(RequestViewHTTP.java:306) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.5]

    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.visualizers.RequestViewHTTP.setSamplerResult(RequestViewHTTP.java:216) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.5]

    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RequestPanel.setSamplerResult(RequestPanel.java:116) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]

    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SamplerResultTab.setupTabPane(SamplerResultTab.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]

    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:395) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]

    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:373) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]

    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I tried this request on postman and I have no problem. Is there someone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The "error" you're getting is not connected with sending the request, it's rather rendering it using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), most probably you chose some rendering format which doesn't match JSON or using [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) method instead of [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) or whatever.

If your request works fine in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and parameterize it as required

Also be informed of [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler which has nice feature or streaming the file directly to the backend without loading it into memory first, check out [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/VDqXDNDCr6w) thread for more details.

HTTP Raw Request sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)